# function name + tab does not return docstring in IPython

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, docstring, tab-completion

In IPython, I am used to write

> function(

and then strike a tab, and get the contents of the docstring and a list of the named arguments. However, this stopped working since I installed IPython 2.0. Is there an explanation or a know fix?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Oh, the shortcut is now `shift+tab`.

Comment: Works inside jupyter notebook, but sadly enough not inside ipython terminal...

Answer (score 4):

`Shift-tab` only works when you place the edit cursor ***inside*** or ***after*** the object. Not when it's at the ***start*** of the object. This gotcha is not documented anywhere...!

I filed jupyter issue [Shift-Tab completion doesn't work when edit cursor is at the start of the object #1902](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1902)

Comment: been wondering why none of my docstrings were showing up hahaha.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

To display docstrings in Python one can use `?` character as a shorthand.

You can place the `?` character before or after (no space allowed) the object you are looking for docs.

To access the source code simply use `??` instead.

Source: [Help and Documentation in IPython](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.01-help-and-documentation.html)