# Dock-string for Jupyter notebook in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

When I want to see the dock-string of some function in pyCharm all I usually do is ctrl-Q.
When I want to do the same in jupyter notebook, it is shift-tab.
The problem is when I run jupyter notebook on pycharm, it shows nothing or some basic usefulness information.
Please advice!

Comment: As per the user posted on another answer, it is this [`shift+tab`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22850810/4237323)